# FParsec ‘many’ primitive fails when stream.UserState updated

Tags: f#, fparsec

The following routine is a minor and simplified change of the [official documentation, "Tracing a parser"](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/debugging-a-parser.html#tracing-a-parser)“ parser tracing wrapper.

```
let (<!>) (parser: Parser<_,USER_STATE>) label : Parser<_,USER_STATE> =
    fun stream ->
        do stream.UserState <- stream.UserState  // <= works if commented out!
        let reply = parser stream
        reply
```

This wrapper allows inspection of `reply` as parsers execute and the updating of `stream.UserState` as needed.

NOTE: this code just copies `stream.UserState` onto itself, effectively doing nothing, because that is the minimum operation for the following error.  The [official documentation manipulating stream.UserState ("Recursive grammers with nesting restrictions”)](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-with-user-state.html#recursive-grammars-with-nesting-restrictions) manipulates `stream.UserState` much more...

Commenting out `do stream.UserState <- stream.UserState` at line 3 allows both repeating (list-producing) and non-repeating FParsec primitives ***to succeed***.  For these list-producing primitives the last subordinate parser failure is unwound and the application of, for example, `many` succeeds.

If `parser` in the above wrapper is *NOT* an FParsec primitive that creates a list of results (like `many` or `sepEndBy`), from the repeated application of subordinate parsers ***then this code parses successfully***.

If `parser` *IS* an FParsec repeating primitive (e.g. `many` or `sepEndBy`), then the failure of the subordinate parser application is passed back out as the failure also of the repeating FParsec primitive - ***an unexpected failure***.

Why does including `do stream.UserState <- stream.UserState` cause FParsec primitives like `many` to fail?

EDIT1: Please note that the [FParsec documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-with-user-state.html#recursive-grammars-with-nesting-restrictions) does an assignment to `stream.UserState` as done in this question.  @brianbern, I don't understand from your post how what I am doing is wrong given the documentation.  Thanks!

How does one assign to `stream.UserState` without breaking calls to the FParsec `many` primitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the setter for `CharStream.UserState` increments the stream's `StateTag` as a side-effect. From the [FParsec source code](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/blob/fdd990ad5abe32fd65d926005b4c7bd71dd2384f/FParsecCS/CharStream.cs#L3803):

```
public TUserState UserState {
    get { return _UserState; }
    set { _UserState = value; ++StateTag; }
}
```

So when you assign the stream's `UserState` to itself, it's **not** the same as doing nothing.

UPDATE: The documentation for the “[many](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.many)” parser states:

> The parser `many p` repeatedly applies the parser `p` until `p` fails. It returns a list of the results returned by `p`. **At the end of the sequence `p` must fail without changing the parser state** and without signalling a `FatalError`, otherwise `many p` will fail with the error reported by `p`.

The example in the FParsec documentation doesn't modify the parser state at the end of the sequence, but your example parser modifies the parser state every time it is called.

Comment: The FParsec documentation does an assignment to stream.UserState as done in this question.  How does one assign to ```stream.UserState``` without breaking calls to the FParsec ```many``` primitive?

Comment: OK, I'll try to update my answer to explain further.

Comment: Excellent catch!  Not sure how I'm going to do what I need to do yet but at least I have a clue.  Thank you @brianberns.

Comment: @user:558823 @'Stephan Tolksdorf' @Stephan Tolksdorf Why doesn't FParsec primitives like ```many``` unwind UserState to the last UserState (and counter) just before the failed application of the repetitively applied sub-parser?  Primitive ```many``` currently fails if the final repetitively-applied subordinate parser fails.  This breaks the documented parser-trace function (http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-with-user-state.html#recursive-grammars-with-nesting-restrictions) if applied to the ```many``` primitive or similar primitives that produce a list of parser results.

Comment: I hope he responds, but I think the basic reason is performance. If every primitive saved the user state when it started, parsers would be much slower overall. It's a lot like a database transaction - you as the developer have to decide when to start a transaction, and then when to commit it or roll it back (via the `attempt` primitive).